# IBM MQ connectivity issue from Mule - UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE and no mqjbnd Error

Tags: ssl, mule, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect MQ from mule as a client mode.  Able to connect, no issues.

But when I enabled SSL with Cipher suite "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", facing error as UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE, hence enabled the MQ tracer as per IBM technote, now I am getting no mqjbnd in java.library.path error.

Code snippet:-

```
<spring:bean id="ConnectionFactory" name="ConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
     <spring:property name="hostName" value="xxxx" />
     <spring:property name="port" value="xxxx"/>
     <spring:property name="queueManager" value="xxxx"/>
     <spring:property name="transportType" value="1"/>
     <spring:property name="sSLCipherSuite" value="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"/>
     <spring:property name="channel" value="xxxx"/>
</spring:bean>

<jms:connector name="JMS" username="xxxx" password="xxxx" specification="1.1" connectionFactory-ref="ConnectionFactory" numberOfConsumers="1" validateConnections="true"  persistentDelivery="true" doc:name="JMS"/>
```

Error -

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentStartException: MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400' ('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE').
        at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.start(DefaultMuleApplication.java:178) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$4.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:106) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:137) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.start(ArtifactWrapper.java:101) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:73) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:536) [mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:333) [mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:325) [mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:100) [mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:298) [mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:156) [mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:139) [mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:172) [mule-module-launcher-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:52) [mule-module-reboot-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:2788) [wrapper-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
Caused by: org.mule.retry.RetryPolicyExhaustedException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'XXXX' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'null'.
        at org.mule.retry.policies.AbstractPolicyTemplate.execute(AbstractPolicyTemplate.java:111) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.connect(AbstractConnector.java:1658) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector.connect(JmsConnector.java:483) ~[mule-transport-jms-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector.start(AbstractConnector.java:449) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.phases.DefaultLifecyclePhase.applyLifecycle(DefaultLifecyclePhase.java:230) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.doApplyLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:108) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleCallback.onTransition(RegistryLifecycleCallback.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.RegistryLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(RegistryLifecycleManager.java:134) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.fireLifecycle(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:88) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.fireLifecycle(MuleRegistryHelper.java:141) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:74) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager$MuleContextLifecycleCallback.onTransition(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:70) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:146) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.lifecycle.MuleContextLifecycleManager.fireLifecycle(MuleContextLifecycleManager.java:62) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
        at org.mule.DefaultMuleContext.start(DefaultMuleContext.java:320) ~[mule-core-3.9.0.jar:3.9.0]
```

Few notes -

1) No clue why I am getting Cipher suite error since I am able to successfully connect to the same MQ from other java program with same Cipher.

2) Also I am trying to connect as Client [TransportType=1] as per MQ client tracer log it is trying to connect as Binding rather than client.

3) I am using OpenJDK-1.8, MQ-8.0.0.2 server and tried with MQ-java client as  7.5.0.0

4) I have specified `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false`

Can anyone guide me what I am missing here.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on mqjbnd error scenario Josh.  I am using OpenJDK-1.8 and MQ-8.0.0.2 with MQ-java client as 7.5.  Below are the traces -

Comment: added the trace.

Comment: Try with `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false`.  If you are using a non-IBM JRE this is required where the IBM names for CipherSuites do not match the "Oracle" names for CipherSuites.

Comment: Josh, I am running with -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false only since i am trying with non-ibm jre.  And if we refer the technote, looks like I am using the same cipher been mentioned for oracle jdk.

Comment: However just tried by adding ibm jre cipher too, still getting the same error. . Root Exception was: Unsupported ciphersuite SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA. Type: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 2018-01-27 00:46:36,067 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] ERROR org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication -

Comment: one catch with pointing the ibm jre - got the below error in addition. hope so it is expecting ibm package.  java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name com.ibm.mq.jmqi.internal.amq6090, locale en_US
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1573)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1396)
        at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:782)

Comment: Manifest detail below - I will try with 8 or 9 client now and let you know.  -bash-4.2$ unzip -p mq-7.5.0.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Specification-Version: 7.5.0.0
Specification-Vendor: IBM Corporation
Implementation-Version: 7.5.0.0 - p000-L120604
Class-Path: com.ibm.mq.headers.jar com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar com.ibm.mq.jmqi.
 jar connector.jar com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar

Comment: trying with mq-9 java client now.  New error.   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSRuntimeException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_161]

Comment: Tried with 8.0.0.2 client also, same error what got it with 9.x.  Just FYR.  
  -bash-4.1$ unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title: WebSphere MQ classes for Java
Specification-Version: 8.0.0.2
Specification-Vendor: IBM Corporation
Implementation-Title: WebSphere MQ classes for Java
Implementation-Version: 8.0.0.2 - p800-002-150217.2
Implementation-Vendor: IBM Corporation
Main-Class: com.ibm.mq.MQJavaLevel
Class-Path: com.ibm.mq.headers.jar com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar com.ibm.mq.jmqi.
 jar

Comment: Yes, I have added the jms.jar[2.0].  Now JMSRuntimeException resolved and getting channel negotiation error.  Verified all the configuration between both Server and client, looks ok.  Enabled the FFDC logs ---  Cause:1       :-  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmatched braces in the pattern.
|   |   Message:1     :-  Unmatched braces in the pattern.
|   |   StackTrace:1  :-  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unmatched braces in the pattern.
|   |           at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(MessageFormat.java:508)

Comment: Sure, Can you please write-up your answer, i will accept it.

Comment: Channel negotiation issue also resolved after upgrade my client to 9.x from 8.0.0.2.  Reference link  -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409006/ibm-mq8-0-amq9503-channel-negotiation-failed

Comment: Hi Som, I added a few of the details about the versions you were running when you received the initial error to your question.  I wrote up an answer as well and have cleaned up my comments related to the initial error.  Note that the accepted answer on the "Channel negotiation failed" question you linked to is from me as well, if this helped you resolve your issue I would appreciate if you gave that answer an up vote as well.  Glad to help you find a working solution.

Comment: Also please remove any of the comments that are now covered in the question or answer.

Comment: Done Josh,  no more issue now - working with your solution.  I accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the `mqjbnd` error.  `mqjbnd` is used only in a binding mode connection to a local queue manager on the same server.  When you turn on tracing the java client will look for this file to log information about it to the trace file.  In client mode it is not used so is a harmless error.

[APAR IC89380](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC89380) describes why `mqjbnd` is used:

> ```
> | The native library 'mqjbnd' is used by the WebSphere MQ
> | classes for Java and WebSphere MQ classes for JMS when
> | creating a connection to the queue manager using a 'bindings'
> | mode connection. A bindings mode connection is a connection
> | which uses the system's memory to communicate with the queue
> | manager, as opposed to a 'client' mode connection which uses
> | a TCP/IP socket.
> ```

---

[APAR IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840), that added the ability to use non-IBM JRE (ie Oracle/OpenJDK) CipherSuite names with the addition of the `useIBMCipherMappings` setting, was not present until 7.5.0.5.  Because you are using 7.5.0.0 this setting will have no affect.

Prior to 7.5.0.5 you would be unable to use any CipherSuite with a Oracle/OpenJDK JRE unless it had the same name as the IBM JRE.  All TLSv1.2 CipherSpecs that are supported by IBM MQ v8.0.0.3 and higher queue managers have CipherSuites that are prefixed with `TLS` in a Oracle JRE and `SSL` in a IBM JRE.  At MQ v8.0.0.2 a queue manager will still allow CipherSpec `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA256` which has a CipherSuite name of `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` in both IBM and Oracle/OpenJDK JREs, but since this is deprecated in the next maintenance level it would not be recommended to use this.

---

Solution, upgrade your IBM MQ jar files to a minimum of one of the following levels:

```
Version    Maintenance Level
v7.5       7.5.0.5
v8.0       8.0.0.2
v9.0LTS    9.0.0.0
v9.0CD     9.0.1
```

---

Note that MQ v7.5 goes End of Service from IBM on April 30 2018, so it would be recommended to go with v8.0 or higher.